# How to add change the log level for a log4j appender programmaticaly?

Tags: java, log4j2, sentry

I added a Sentry appender for logging my Error messages. Now Sentry loggs everything. Is it possible to set the Log level of an appender?

I added the Sentry Appender like this:

```
private static void addSentryLogger() {
  LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);

  RegexFilter regexFilter = null;
  try {
    regexFilter = RegexFilter.createFilter("^(.*?([E][R][R][O][R]|[W][A][R][N])[^$]*)$", null, true, Filter.Result.ACCEPT, null);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    System.out.println("Error with regexFilter");
  }

  SentryAppender sentryAppender = SentryAppender.createAppender("Sentry", regexFilter);
  sentryAppender.start();
  lc.getConfiguration().addAppender(sentryAppender);

  lc.getRootLogger().addAppender(lc.getConfiguration()
    .getAppender(sentryAppender.getName()));
  lc.updateLoggers();
}
```

The Regex is ok, but i want to use it for a closer specification. So i want to use the error Level for for filtering ERROR and WARN

I hope somebody out there can help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
((AppenderSkeleton)Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("Sentry")).setThreshold(Level.WARN));
```

Comment: There is no AppenderSkeleton and no getRootLogger available. What imports you used?

Comment: Can you not call `.setThreshold(Level.WARN))` on your existing `sentryAppender` object?

Comment: No, it's log4j2 maybe thats why it's not possible